# Force ATi Mobility Radeon to Use 3D Support

Tags: drivers, unity, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I'm not sure if I'm asking the right question here.

I recently downgraded from 16.04 to 14.04 on my IBM Thinkpad T42 and I noticed that if I try to use Unity, it lags like high hell, and that the graphics card, an ancient ATi Mobility Radeon 7500 does not support the 3D interface that Unity needs to function properly. Is there any way where I can force the graphics card to use 3D Support or be able to run Unity?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is there any way where I can force the graphics card to use 3D Support or be able to run Unity?*

No, there isn't. An ATI Mobility Radeon 7500 is too old for that.

Consider using Ubuntu variants like Xubuntu or Lubuntu that run less demanding desktop environments.